# Haxe Reflection - Subclasses and Interfaces

Tags: inheritance, reflection, types, haxe

I can use the Haxe Type Class to reflect an object's class e.g.

```
getClass<T> (o:T):Class<T>
```

Is there a way to check whether a given object implements an interface or is a subclass of another class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Std.is](http://api.haxe.org/Std.html#is):

```
class Subclass extends OriginalClass implements IMyInterface {}

var myObj = new Subclass();

var isClass = Std.is(myObj, OriginalClass);      // returns true
var isSubclass = Std.is(myObj, Subclass);        // also returns true
var isInterface = Std.is(myObj, IMyInterface);   // also returns true
```

Will return "true" if the second argument is the class of the object, one of its parent classes, or an interface it implements.